# Two columns with two legend items in highchars.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

**i need this in highcharts.js:**

- two columns
- two items in legeneds - each for column with own colors
- label bottom of each columns

**as you can seen on bottom placed image**

i have this - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9ZYN/) - but legends have only one item..

```
var options = {
   "chart":{
       'renderTo': 'container',
      "type":"column"
   },
   "title":{
      "text":"",
      "style":{
         "display":"none"
      }
   },
   "xAxis":{
      "categories":[
         "Average",
         "Your value"
      ],
      "title":{
         "text":"x label",
         "style":{
            "font":"bold 16px Verdana",
            "color":"#000"
         }
      }
   },
   "yAxis":{
      "min":0,
      "title":{
         "text":"y label",
         "style":{
            "font":"bold 16px Verdana",
            "color":"#000"
         }
      }
   },
   "legend":{
      "align":"center",
      "itemDistance":20,
      "verticalAlign":"top",
      "margin":25,
      "floating":false,
      "borderColor":"#CCC",
      "borderWidth":1,
      "shadow":false,
      "borderRadius":0
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "color":"#0066FF",
         "data":[
            {
               "y":50,
               "color":"#372A4B"
            },
            {
               "y":30,
               "color":"#1EC37A"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

or this - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9ZYN/1/) - but no bottom label for each column

```
var options = {
   "chart":{
       'renderTo': 'container',
      "type":"column"
   },
   "title":{
      "text":"",
      "style":{
         "display":"none"
      }
   },
   "xAxis":{
        "categories":[
         ["Average"],
         ["Your value"]
      ],
      "title":{
         "text":"x label",
         "style":{
            "font":"bold 16px Verdana",
            "color":"#000"
         }
      }
   },
   "yAxis":{
      "min":0,
      "title":{
         "text":"y label",
         "style":{
            "font":"bold 16px Verdana",
            "color":"#000"
         }
      }
   },
   "legend":{
      "align":"center",
      "itemDistance":20,
      "verticalAlign":"top",
      "margin":25,
      "floating":false,
      "borderColor":"#CCC",
      "borderWidth":1,
      "shadow":false,
      "borderRadius":0
   },
      labels: {
            items: [{
                html: "Legend 1",
                style: {
                    top: '10px',
                    left: '20px',
                    height: '30px'
                }
            }, {
                html: "Legend 2",
                style: {
                    top: '10px',
                    left: '120px',
                    height: '30px'
                }
            }]
        },
   "series":[
      {
         "color":"#372A4B",
         "name": "Average",
         "data":[
            {
               "y":50
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "color":"#1EC37A",
         "name": "Your value",
         "data":[
            {
               "y":30,
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

**but what i need is exactly as you can see on this image:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et8eb/).  Is that what you are after?

Achieved with:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
```

And adding zero onto the stack:

```
  "series":[
   {
      "color":"#372A4B",
       data: [85, 0],
       name: "Average"
    },
    {
       "color":"#1EC37A",
       data: [0, 63.11],
       name: "Your Value"
    }]
```

Comment: excelent, i have this before - `without stacking: 'normal'` what this do exactly ?

Comment: @patie, without stacking the each series columns are placed adjacent to each other, with stacking normal, they are placed on top of each other.  Essentially it's a hack to remove the a blank space on the axis.

Answer (score 1):

I can get close using stackLabels, but the labels are in the plot area, not outside the axis.

```
    stackLabels: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'gray'
        },
        formatter: function () {
            return this.stack;
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/rZKwq/1/

Comment: too close, but i need it outside